# How to encode categorical features in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-1.2

I have a set of data based on which I want to create a classification model. Each row has the following form:

```
user1,class1,product1
user1,class1,product2
user1,class1,product5
user2,class1,product2
user2,class1,product5
user3,class2,product1
```

There are about 1M users, 2 classes, and 1M products. What I would like to do next is create the sparse vectors (something already supported by MLlib) BUT in order to apply that function I have to create the dense vectors (with the 0s), first. In other words, I have to binarize my data. What's the easiest (or most elegant) way of doing that?

Given that I am a newbie in regards to MLlib, may I ask you to provide a concrete example? I am using MLlib 1.2.

**EDIT**

I have ended up with the following piece of code but is turns out to be really slow... Any other ideas provided that I can only use MLlib 1.2?

```
val data = test11.map(x=> ((x(0) , x(1)) , x(2))).groupByKey().map(x=> (x._1 , x._2.toArray)).map{x=>
  var lt : Array[Double] = new Array[Double](test12.size)
  val id = x._1._1
  val cl = x._1._2
  val dt = x._2
  var i = -1
  test12.foreach{y => i += 1; lt(i) = if(dt contains y) 1.0 else 0.0}
  val vs = Vectors.dense(lt)
  (id , cl , vs)
}
```

Comment: Can give you an example of what you'd like the dense vector output to look like for that input?

Comment: what kind of classification do you want to do exactly? i.e. if `userX` and `classY` then it most probably will be `productZ` or something else?

Comment: not really. I am gonna use binary classification where `userX` is a sparse vector of values and `classY` is the corresponding class.

Comment: @user706838 is `userX` an actual object or a very simple string? and are you taking into account `product` in any way during the classification?

Comment: What I am asking here, I think, is very straight forward for someone who has work with machine learning before. I am just trying to find out the best way to implement this in MLlib. Have a look here for similar example in scikit-learn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I use Scala and MLlib 1.2 Please have a look on my edit.

Answer (score 9):

You can use spark.ml's [OneHotEncoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder).

You first use:

```
OneHotEncoder.categories(rdd, categoricalFields)
```

Where `categoricalField` is the sequence of indexes at which your `RDD` contains categorical data. `categories`, given a dataset and the index of columns which are categorical variables, returns a structure that, for each field, describes the values that are present for in the dataset. That map is meant to be used as input to the encode method:

```
OneHotEncoder.encode(rdd, categories)
```

Which returns your vectorized `RDD[Array[T]]`.

Comment: which is not available in MLlib 1.2 :-)

Comment: Yeah, is it not, and I cannot update unfortunately... Please have a look on my edit.

Comment: This doesn't even seem to be available in 1.4.

Answer (score 4):

If using built-in `OneHotEncoder` is not an option and you have only a single variable implementing poor man's one-hot is more or less straightforward. First lets create an example data:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(
    Array("user1", "class1", "product1"),
    Array("user1", "class1", "product2"),
    Array("user1", "class1", "product5"),
    Array("user2", "class1", "product2"),
    Array("user2", "class1", "product5"),
    Array("user3", "class2", "product1")))
```

Next we have to create a mapping from a value to the index:

```
val prodMap = sc.broadcast(rdd.map(_(2)).distinct.zipWithIndex.collectAsMap)
```

and a simple encoding function:

```
def encodeProducts(products: Iterable[String]): Vector =  {
    Vectors.sparse(
        prodMap.value.size,
        products.map(product => (prodMap.value(product).toInt, 1.0)).toSeq
    )
}
```

Finally we can apply it to the dataset:

```
rdd.map(x => ((x(0), x(1)), x(2))).groupByKey.mapValues(encodeProducts)
```

It is relatively easy to extend above to handle multiple variables.

**Edit**:

If number of products is to large to make broadcasting useful it should be possible to use `join` instead. First we can create similar mapping from product to index but keep it as a RDD:

```
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner

val nPartitions = ???

val prodMapRDD = rdd
     .map(_(2))
     .distinct
     .zipWithIndex
     .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(nPartitions))
     .cache

val nProducts = prodMapRDD.count // Should be < Int.MaxValue
```

Next we reshape input `RDD` to get `PairRDD` indexed by product:

```
val pairs = rdd
    .map(rec => (rec(2), (rec(0), rec(1))))
    .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(nPartitions))
```

Finally we can `join` both

```
def indicesToVec(n: Int)(indices: Iterable[Long]): Vector = {
     Vectors.sparse(n, indices.map(x => (x.toInt, 1.0)).toSeq)
}

pairs.join(prodMapRDD)
   .values
   .groupByKey
   .mapValues(indicesToVec(nProducts.toInt))
```

Comment: +1 for the general solution. Do you have another solution which does not use `broadcast`? I use the solution like yours but sometimes this is not working because the `prodMap` is too big to broadcast.

Comment: @emeth It is much more expensive but it should be possible you use joins. Please see an edit for details.

Answer (score -1):

Original question asks for the easiest way to specify categorical features from non-categorical.

In Spark ML, you can use VectorIndexer's setMaxCategories method, where you do not have to specify the fields - instead, it will understand as categorical those fields with lower or equal cardinality than a given number (in this case, 2).

```
val indexer = new VectorIndexer()
.setInputCol("features")
.setOutputCol("indexed")
.setMaxCategories(10)
```

Please see [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47776862/3702859) for details.